# How can we define that the five integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ are all natural numbers that are different from 1 to 10

Tags: equation-solving

I would appreciate it if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: How can we define that the five integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ are all natural numbers that are different from 1 to 10?

My work

{a, b, c, d, e, f} /.
Solve[a < b > c > d < e < f &&1<={a,b,c,d,e,f}<=10 && {a, b, c, d,
e, f}, Integers]

I would like to add an additional condition that they are different to the above input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem specification would require clarification, but are you possibly looking for something like this?

```
With[{v = {a, b, c, d, e}}, 
 Solve[
  Element[Alternatives @@ v, Integers] && (* all are integers *)
   1 <= v <= 10 && (* between 1 and 10 inclusive *)
   Less @@ v (* a < b < c < d < e *)]]
```

This returns 252 solutions.

Comment: Note that OP writes "are different from 1 to 10".

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you need? (252 ordered solutions)

```
Subsets[Range[10], {5}]
(*     {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 7},
        ...
        {5, 6, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}    *)
```

Or this? (30240 unordered solutions)

```
Join @@ Permutations /@ Subsets[Range[10], {5}]
(*    {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 3, 5},
       ...
       {10, 9, 7, 8, 6}, {10, 9, 8, 6, 7}, {10, 9, 8, 7, 6}}    *)
```